Creating [slug].tsx in Next.js Page router
I am trying to develop an app in Next.js using the page router framework. So for each component I have page.tsx under relevant folder name. For a particular component I need to have slug for routing, which directory should I create the [slug].tsx ? Is it where the main component resides or along with the page.tsx as sibling under the component folder name ?
Component has A , B , C folder
(route) has a > page.tsx , b > page.tsx, c >page.tsx 

// /components/RecipeCard.tsx
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { slugify } from '@/app/utils/slugify';
import { Box, Button, Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Container, Grid, Popover, Typography } from '@mui/material';

interface RecipeCardProps {
  recipe: {
    uri: string;
    label: string;
    image: string;
    ingredientLines: string[];
  };
}

const RecipeCard: React.FC<RecipeCardProps> = ({ recipe }) => {
  const slug = slugify(recipe.label);

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);


  return (
   
          <Card>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              height="140"
              image={recipe.image}
              alt={recipe.label} 
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                {recipe.label}
              </Typography>             
              <Button
                aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
                onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
                variant="contained"
              >
                  Ingredients
                </Button>
                <Popover
                  id="mouse-over-popover"
                  sx={{
                    pointerEvents: 'none',
                  }}
                  open={open}
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'bottom',
                    horizontal: 'left',
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'left',
                  }}
                  onClose={handlePopoverClose}
                  disableRestoreFocus
                >
                  <Typography sx={{ p: 1 }}>
                    {recipe.ingredientLines.slice(0, 3).join(', ')}...
                  </Typography>
                </Popover>

                <Link href={`/recipes/${slug}?uri=${encodeURIComponent(recipe.uri)}`}  passHref>
              <Button variant="contained" >
                View Details
              </Button>
              </Link>             
            </CardContent>
          </Card>      
  );
};

export default RecipeCard;

// pages/recipes/[slug].tsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Container, Typography, CircularProgress, Card, CardContent, CardMedia } from '@mui/material';

const APP_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ID;
const APP_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_KEY;

interface RecipeDetailsProps {
  label: string;
  image: string;
  ingredientLines: string[];
  calories: number;
}
 
const RecipeDetailInfo = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query;
  const [recipe, setRecipe] = useState<RecipeDetailsProps | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipe = async () => {
      if (!router.query.uri) return;

      const uri = decodeURIComponent(router.query.uri as string);

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://api.edamam.com/api/recipes/v2/by-uri`,
          {
            params: {
              type: 'public',
              app_id: APP_ID,
              app_key: APP_KEY,
              uri: uri,
            },
          }
        );
        setRecipe(response.data.recipe);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching recipe:', error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchRecipe();
  }, [slug, router.query.uri]);

  if (loading) {
    return <CircularProgress />;
  }

  if (!recipe) {
    return <Typography variant="h6">Recipe not found</Typography>;
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <Card>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="140"
          image={recipe.image}
          alt={recipe.label}
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            {recipe.label}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            {recipe.ingredientLines.join(', ')}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Calories: {Math.round(recipe.calories)}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default RecipeDetailInfo;

Page.tsx pages are under (routing) folder
Recipe detail Page.tsx
import RecipeDetailInfo from "@/app/(recipes)/[slug]";

export default function RecipeDetail(){
    return (
<>
<h1>Recipe Details</h1>;
<RecipeDetailInfo/>
</>   
    )
}

Recipe card Page.tsx
export default function RecipeCard(){
    return <h1>Recipe Card Details</h1>;
}

